# Django - usage of prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-models

no matter how many tutorials/documentation i read i still don't quite understand how exactly i'm supposed to be using prefetch_related.

My models.py:

```
class ProfileComment(models.Model):
    author       = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_posted  = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    body         = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True)
    ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user     = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(ProfileComment, related_name='comments', blank=True)
    avatar   = models.FileField(upload_to=avatar_folder, default='user-avatar/default.png')
    ...
```

My views.py:

```
profile = Profile.objects.prefetch_related('comments').get(user=request.user)
```

And in template:

```
{% for comment in profile.comments.all %}
<div>
  <p>Author: {{ comment.author.user }}</p><img src="{{ comment.author.avatar.url }}">
  <p>Message: {{ comment.body }}</p>
  <p>Date posted: {{ comment.date_posted }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

However, no matter what i put in prefetch_related, amount of queries just go up by like 5 for every record

Comment: `Prefetch_related` will make *extra* queries. For a `.get(user=request.user)` it will not make any difference at all.

Comment: So how can i make it not make another 10 queries for 1 record?

Comment: Currently i have 10 records and it takes 80 queries to load them all

Comment: you *don't*. `.prefetch_related` makes extra queries to minimize *bandwidth* to the database. If you would fetch all comments in the *same* query, you repeat the data for the profile in *each record*. If you would do that for an extra relation, you repeat the data of the profile times the number of rows, and the data of the comment times the other relation.

Comment: that is because of the `comment.author.user` part. That can be optimized with a `.select_related`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) should be used to fetch related objects for a queryset *in bulk*. Since you write:

```
….get(user=request.user)
```

however it will not make any difference, since you only retrieve a *single* object, and it will thus prefetch the comments in an extra query.

What you can minimize however is the number of extra queries that originate from `comment.author.user`. This will make two extra queries *per* comment, since `ForeignKey`s are loaded lazily.

Your view can thus look like:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
comments = profile.comments.select_related('author', 'author__user')
```

where you pass both `profile` and `comments` to the template, and then retrieve it with:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
<div>
  <p>Author: {{ comment.author.user }}</p><img src="{{ comment.author.avatar.url }}">
  <p>Message: {{ comment.body }}</p>
  <p>Date posted: {{ comment.date_posted }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

here we thus read the comments from a queryset where we fetch the profile and the user of that profile in the same query. As a result we will make two queries: one for the `Profile`, and one for all the `Comment`s including the `.author` and `.author.user`.

Comment: thank you, this really helped with the confusion